# typescript: react-query useQuery data after reassigning type narrowing doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

In react-query, data value of useQuery result is `T | undefined`. if I narrow down the type, it works. However, if I reassign it to a different variable, type narrowing stops working. It only happens when the reassigned data is referred inside callbacks, seems like. What is the issue here?

```
  const { data } = useQuery<number[]>("test", () => [1, 2, 3, 4]);

  let data2 = data;
  // filtering and sorting data here...

  const fun0 = () => {
    if (!data) return;

    //No error
    [1, 2, 3].map((one) => data[0]);
  };

  const fun = () => {
    if (!data2) return;

    //This works
    const foo = data2[0];

    //Type error here. data2 is still number[] | undefined ???
    [1, 2, 3].map((one) => data2[0]);
  };
```

You can see an example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-query-typescript-issue-te51lx?file=/src/App.tsx:96-455) (Updated: With solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not the re-assignment but rather that `data` is `const` and `data2` is `let`. This will also reproduce the issue:

```
const data = null! as number[] | undefined

let data2 = null! as number[] | undefined
```

Generally, when you are using `let` variables and narrow them, this information is not available inside of callbacks. After all, it is not known to the compiler if the variable was changed before the callback is executed. `const` variables can not be reassigned, so the value should theoretically not change (*if the variable is some kind of nested object, you could modify the nested properties even if the variable is declared as `const`. But the compiler is smart enough to differentiate those scenarios. See this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCKz1QJ5wC+cAZlBCHAERToCGAxjALQCOO+VA3AFA8MQAdqngATOjDpwAvIh5w4dAFxxByADbqAhItSrkIAEa4A2gF04AHxSDR6EsEHpRPQn3XoxEugCYZchWV9TR06PTUjUwtrZFt7R2dXPgFheBJYgAZ-AAoAShkAPgC4YBI4bK1xSQA6OnzaGGQoQV55OAB6doA5CDhccig2kwBGABo4H3GAZjNqkDowbOyhdHzpIqq6WpMMs1zeQlaUkVJYnLWihDbS8srvH1r6zyaWvgVOgBUAC2A9AHdoABrVBtY5pCC9WSbB50HZmVrvdrQkrhAzGKDmKw2OwOJwuBQjcaTOAzOYLJYrC5waHbXb7Vy8IA)*)

See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50580) or for a more in-depth-read [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCKz1QJ5wC+cAZlBCHAERToCGAxjALQCOO+VA3AFA8MQAdqngATOjDpwAvHEHIANgoCEcOqjnIQAI1wBtALpwAPikGj0JYIPSi+C9GIl0ATDM1LV6zTv1HTyOaW1rZ8AsLwJIEADO4AFACUMgB8iDxwcMAkcHHK4pJJtDDIUIK86XAA9JUAchBwuORQFXoAjAA0cC6dAMwGAHQgdGBxcULoSdKp+XR60QYJvITl4SKkgfGTqQgVWTl5zi6FjiVlfBnVACoAFsAaAO7QANaoFauREPWyMy5zBuUXSo-TIaeS+KCGExmCxWGx2DJtTrdOB9QbDUbjLZwH5-RY8ZY8IA)

Comment: Thanks! That is really good to know. What would be the best solution here? Should I make a new const for each processing `const filteredData = myFilter(data); const sortedData = mySort(filteredData); ...`?

Comment: @XunYang - hard to say. But you could just check in one place if `data` is undefined or not, then assign it to a new variable and use the new non-undefine variable everywhere.

Comment: That sounds like a very good solution. Thanks again!